# What's the probability of the following scenario regarding phone numbers?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Given that a phone number has to be 7 digits and that the first digit cannot be 0 or 1, what's the probability that a phone number contains at least one '8' and one '6'?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You should always show us that you have put some effort into trying to solve the problem. This isn't a site for us to do your homework.

Comment: Oh, I have tried 6*8^6 over 8*10^6, but it seems like that it's the probability of at least one '8' or '6'.

Comment: 6*8^6 = 1572864?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle in order to count the amount of such numbers:

- Include the amount of numbers: $(10-2)^1\cdot(10)^{7-1}=8000000$
- Exclude the amount of numbers without "6": $(10-3)^1\cdot(10-1)^{7-1}=3720087$
- Exclude the amount of numbers without "8": $(10-3)^1\cdot(10-1)^{7-1}=3720087$
- Include the amount of numbers without both: $(10-4)^1\cdot(10-2)^{7-1}=1572864$

---

Hence the amount of such numbers is:

$$8000000-3720087-3720087+1572864=2132690$$

---

Hence the probability of such number is:

$$\frac{2132690}{8000000}=26.658625\%$$

Comment: @user296326: You're welcome. Please try to improve your question (for example, add your attempts to solve it on your own, as written in your on comments to the question), otherwise it will be closed.