# What is the probability of a 7 digit phone number having one given digit

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a 7-digit phone number contains at least one 6? (Repetition of numbers and lead zero are allowed).

Given the basic probability formula

> P(E) = N(E)/N(S)

Where **N(E)** is the number of outcomes in E and **N(S)** is the number of outcomes in S.

I figure that since repetition and leading zeros are allowed I have **10^7** possible phone numbers in S, and the probability of getting a phone number with at least one 6 is **N(E)**.

I tried to use [the inclusion/exclusion principle talked about in this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562226/whats-the-probability-of-the-following-scenario-regarding-phone-numbers), and these are my thoughts based on what I understood.

> Include the amount of numbers: 10^7
>
> Exclude the amount of numbers without a single given digit: 3720087

Simple algebra then leads to a fraction of **6279913/10^7** and a percentage of **~63%**. I rounded at thousandths place and placed in an answer **.628**. Could someone correct me where I went wrong applying this technique? Or show me another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of a phone number containing *at least one 6* is the complement of a phone number containing *no 6's* so:

All possible phone numbers = $10^7$

Phone numbers with no 6 = $9^7$

Probability of random number containing no 6: $9^7/10^7$ = $0.4782969$

Probability of random number containing at least one 6: $1-(9^7/10^7) = 0.5217031$

Comment: Please, as the answerer, conform to the Mathjax standard. Formating tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense. My mistake was trying to count the number of sixes beyond the first.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of seeing this is looking at the complementary event : "a 7-digit phone number contains no 6".
Counting the number of such phone numbers is easy: there are $9 \times 9 \times \dots \times 9 = 9^7$ possibilities in this event. As there are $10^7$ possibilities in total, the probability you are looking for is $1-\left(\frac{9}{10})\right)^7$.
This is equal to 0.5217031.